# text overflow in absolute position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

Please help to fix this issue:
[image]

The `help-block` is inside `form-group`. I'm using bootstrap + form validator plugin

```
css used:

    .form-group.has-error .help-block {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #B20005;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        color: #B20005;
    }
```

Comment: can you add you html and css in jsfiddle

Comment: Add complete fiddle or complete html & css files.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.form-group.has-error .help-block {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .form-group.has-error .help-block {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: tried. but not working. Actually the absolute position is inside a relative container.